# SWIG: How to add namespace to generated cs file？

Tags: swig

i am using swig to gen c# code, but i don't know how to add a namespace to the output file,
such as:
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
my English is poor, can anyone understand?

Comment: Do you mean adding `using System.Text` to the generated code?  If so just enclose code to insert in `%{` and `%}`.

Comment: thank you very much! i use typemap(csimports) to do it